# Android - Audio recorder FileNotFound

Tags: android, audio, file-not-found, recorder

I'm trying to record audio

```
this.recorder = new android.media.MediaRecorder();
this.recorder.setAudioSource(android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);      this.recorder.setOutputFormat(android.media.MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
this.recorder.setAudioEncoder(android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
this.recorder.setOutputFile("pruebaAudioRecorder.mp4");
**this.recorder.prepare();**
this.recorder.start();
```

but when i call prepare method throws the FileNotFound exception.

- Should I create the file before prepare method? something like `new File(...)`
- If so, which should be the file path?

thx a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a great solution, remember to add the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

http://www.benmccann.com/blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/